# Не проходит DELETE-запрос

Tags: javascript, клиент-сервер

При совершении DELETE-запроса выбрасывает ошибку:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:30117/api/Goods 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:30117/api/Goods. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'http://localhost:8070' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
>   request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

На Web Api сервере включен CORS. На клиенте для отправки запроса использую
модуль **request**:

```
function _delete(tableName, id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            method: "DELETE",
            url: `${_serverAddress}/${tableName}`,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json"
            }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

GET-запросы работают нормально.

Comment: Ошибка оказалась достаточно простой: `url: ${_serverAddress}/${tableName}`, в данном месте забыл указать параметр id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо обработать на сервере `OPTIONS`-запрос и выставить соответствующий `Access-Cobtrol-Allow-Origin`.